# CATextLayer is blurry on non-retina display

Tags: retina-display, catextlayer

On a non-retina display (Mac), my `CATextLayer` instances produce text that is blurrier than what I get with `NSAttributedString`'s `-drawAtPoint:`

See for yourself:

[image]

At the top, a `CATextLayer` instance (`contentsScale` property is 1.0, which corresponds to the screen's pixel density), at the bottom, the result of `NSAttributedString`'s `-drawAtPoint:`. Both use the same font and colour.

Changing the `allowsFontSubpixelQuantization` property of `CATextLayer` doesn't make any noticeable difference.

If I set the layer's `contentsScale` to 2.0, the text becomes sharper. But there may be something I missed, because I'm not supposed to set this to 2.0 on a non-retina display, am I?

Note: on a retina display, the difference in sharpness is also noticeable, but less so.

This is on macOS 12.